# Visual Studio Code Intellisense and Autocomplete - Vite, JSconfig and Aliases - can't figure out the right combination

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vite, vscode-jsconfig

Just started working again with Visual studio code after years on PHPStorm/Webstorm

I've decided to take the transition just because of how lightweight VSCode is and because I don't want to rely on a paid service/having it on every computer since VSCode is almost everywhere and free.

I started fresh

Vite + Vue3

Now I've come across several issues with
Imports
CTRL+Click - goto reference
Autocompletes

my Vite.config is as follows - to enable aliases

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "url";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import path from "path";
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
/// <reference types="vitest" />
export default defineConfig({
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".json", ".vue", ".scss", ".css"],
        fallback: {
            crypto: path.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
            stream: path.resolve("stream-browserify"),
        },
        alias: {
            "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
            img: path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/img"),
        },
    },
    plugins: [vue()],
    test: {},
    server: {
        port: 8080,
    },
    build: {
        sourcemap: false,
        minify: false,
        assetsDir: "chunks",
    },
    css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            scss: {
                additionalData: `@use  "sass:math"; @import "./src/assets/scss/v2/legacy.scss"; @import "./src/assets/scss/common.scss";`,
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Now, with vite config alone I can import using the "@" alias - but no intellisense is taking place,
I can't autocomplete imports nor can I ctrl + click

After adding a jsconfig.json file

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["src/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

I am now able to import my components using the "@" and also have full intellisense on them and can CTRL+click them
BUT, now I've lost the ability to import node_modules - lost all intellisense on that

So, if I use my vite/jsconfig I can ctrl+click/have auto complete on "@" alias
but I lost my node_module import capabilities

If I remove those vite.config alias configuration and remove jsconfig
I get back node_module intellisense and lost my project's intellisense.

What am I missing here? please help me figure this out.

I've also removed any / every npm import extension just so that I can understand how this works

Comment: You're using both  Vite's and the paths configurations in your `jsconfig.json`. Sometimes these conflict with each other. Use One instead

Comment: using only one prevents certain autocomplete and intellisense features from working ALSO, it just doesn't work - seems like I need vite alias prop for the imports to actually work and I need jsconfig for the intellisense and auto complete to work but then I lose access to node_modules imports

Comment: @AbdullaNilam
If i take out jsconfig, I can import from nodemodules and the '@' import alias works - but I cannot "point + click" to go go files with the "@" import alias

I also can't go to .vue files regardless
if i take out vite alias - alias imports doesn't work at all

Answer (score 8):

The problem that you have here because of `jsconfig.json` file.

The presence of `jsconfig.json` file in a directory indicates that the directory is the root of a JavaScript Project. The jsconfig.json file specifies the root files and the options for the features provided by the JavaScript language service ([vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_what-is-jsconfigjson)).

Most of the time you don't need it, but there is some examples where u can use it like *IntelliSense customization*. [examples](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_examples)

#### more details:

`jsconfig.json` is a descendant of `tsconfig.json`, which is a configuration file for TypeScript. `jsconfig.json` is `tsconfig.json` with `"allowJs"` attribute set to `true` and since there is no actual compilation is required for *JavaScript*. These attributes exist because `jsconfig.json` is a descendant of `tsconfig.json` (just)

So, not all options are the same here like `target` :

> The `target` setting changes which JS features are downleveled and which are left intact. For example, an arrow function () => this will be turned into an equivalent function expression if target is ES5 or lower.
> Changing `target` also changes the default value of [lib](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib).

With that being said, vscode IntelliSense can be effected by those changes. so if u remove it, everything will works as expected.

In other words `target` can effect IntelliSense on `jsconfig.json`.

For your case, you just need to add it as following:

**jsconfig.json**

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
        "@/*": ["src/*"]
      }
   }
}
```

**vite.config.js**

```
alias: {
  '@/': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
}
```

For more reading about jsconfig.json for vscode: [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig)

Comment: HOLY HELL, This is the one! I just removed the Target and everything just works!

One last issue, though I'm totally gonna vote this as the correct answer

I can now ctrl+click and import using the "@" alias, so thank you; yet I still can't ctrl+click to go to .vue files

Any idea on that specifically ?

Comment: Sounds great Liad! Try to restart vscode if the issue still exist please explain more, like show me the (import statement & current jsconfig file ) that u are trying to preform ctrl+click on. Seems to work fine on my vscode (ctrl+click to go to .vue files).

Comment: Final vite.config:
```
resolve: {
  extensions: [".js", ".json", ".vue", ".scss", ".css"],
  fallback: {
   crypto: path.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
   stream: path.resolve("stream-browserify"),
  },
  alias: {
   "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
   img: path.resolve(__dirname, `./public/img`),
  },
 },
```
and jsconfig.json
```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "paths": {
   "@/*": ["src/*"]
  }
 }
}
```

using the Volar extension.
And still, ctrl+click does not work for vue files, whether i include the vue extension on import or not. using @ alias

Comment: First, let us agree that **baseUrl** must be specified if "paths" is specified, to understand it more u can read this [baseUrl](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#baseUrl). Now based on that lets tallk about **paths** path mapping to be computed relative to **baseUrl** option. So, u need to get those right with your folder structure.
and that's might effect your absolute & relative imports I believe.
You can go over these things and see if u are missing something here.

Comment: Can u share your `folder structure` & `import-statement` that have this issue (and in what file this import statement) if `ctrl+click`  issue still exist !?

Comment: Things not clear at my side cause I can't reproduce the same behavior as yours. Is works fine (On import statement I can `ctrl+clcik` and go to .vue file).

Comment: folder structure:
src/common/components/folderName/componentName

once I 
import componentName from "@/common/components/folderName/componentName.vue"
I can't ctrl+click
my vite config and jsconfig are as you've provided in your magnificent answer.
So I'm really not sure what went wrong here

Comment: rewarded you with the bounty regardless.
You've been a tremendous help so far

Comment: @SohaibAlqasem WHAAAAT…it worked! After hours of scouring the net, thank you! Can you share your project starter setup for vite + react. I am having trouble setting up es-lint

Comment: For anyone who is having trouble with autocomplete not working for alias import i.e. @/components/, your baseUrl must be properly specified with the correct base path.
For me, it was `baseUrl: '.'` and I changed it to `baseUrl: './'`and it started giving me proper suggestions at the import path. Inside - tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue with Visual Studio Code Intellisense and Autocomplete when using Vite, and import Aliases. After trying a few configurations without success, I made some tweaks that resolved the problem for me. Here's the working combination:

**tsconfig.json:**

```json
{
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "paths": {
    "@": ["./src"],
    "@components/*": ["./src/components/*"]
  },
}
```

**vite.config.ts:**

```js
import path from 'path';

export default {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@components": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/components"),
    },
  },
};
```

Make sure to include these configurations in your `tsconfig.json` and `vite.config.ts` files, and Intellisense and Autocomplete should work as expected. Hope this helps!